# How to unbold part of the subsubsection title?

Tags: bold, subsection

I would like to get "**A** (B)". I searched the forum, but it looks those questions are about unbolding the whole section title.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `\subsubsection{A\normalfont{(B)}}` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
\section*{A \mdseries (B)}
```

Some more text needed to save the answer.

Comment: It is the other way the OP asked for: `\subsubsection{A\normalfont{(B)}}` ...

Comment: @Mensch Except  that I did not no paid attention to the type of header, that is irrelevant for the problem, the result is the same in this case, and therefore is also exactly what the OP asked for, but simpler.